# Set a keyboard shortcut in Dolphin for opening the selected file in a text editor

Tags: kde, kate, dolphin-file-manager

Is it possible to set up Dolphin file manager so that, once a file is selected, pressing a keyboard shortcut (for example `Ctrl+E`) will open that file in a text editor (for example, Kate), regardless of file associations?

I have a lot of SVG images that open in Inkscape when double clicked, and that is desirable behaviour, but often it is nice to be nice to open these files in a text editor like Kate. Right clicking on a file, going to the Open With... menu and selecting Kate is quite slow and tedious, especially on a laptop without a mouse. The same thing is applicable for for HTML files, md files, various executable scripts, etc...

Answer (score 0):

[My impression is that was possible in the past](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/11kwvmm/shortcut_for_command_applied_to_selected_files_in/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).
As a workaround:

- install `xclip`
- add a custom shortcut (e.g. Ctrl+K) with the command `kate -b $(xclip -o)`
- after selecting your file, *copy* it (Ctrl+C, which adds it to clipboard);
- use the Kate shortcut above (Ctrl+K)
- you can (might need to) associate a shortcut to "Open klipper at mouse position" in order to quickly see and select in the clipboard list if needed: it might be the case that the last *copied* file is not *selected* in the clipboard list.

[image]

If that's the case, you'll have to press that shortcut *and* Enter to select it in that list, before the Kate shortcut, which makes 4 keyboard actions in total... It might not be needed, in which case you have to do just *two* keyboard actions ...

You might find [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/1076gro/comment/jb97liw/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) helpful too, in order to pop-up an "open with"-like list with shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get xclip to output files copied from Dolphin, due to some meta/mime info copied along with the name; so, I couldn't get what @cipricus suggested. And since I also couldn't find how to get Dolphin to open files based on mime types (for example, all text files) as it only seems to look at file extensions, which I don't use in linux for text files.

So what I did in the end was just start using file extensions. Now all my nginx config files end with `.nginx` and Dolphin is happy and I can edit them by double clicking in Dolphin.